# Method of selecting the optimal average combination of highest numbers?

Tags: optimization, combinations, average

I know of [pairing functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function), but my problem may involve three to five variables. When I have a few robots configured with certain parameters for movement, and I want to evaluate the robots based on how fast ($F$), how jerky ($J$) and how much energy ($E$) they consume, is there a statistical/mathematical technique of choosing the robot that has a high value of $F$, $J$ and $E$?

Eg:
$F$ range = $[0; 100]$, $J$ range = $[0; 1]$, $E$ range = $[0; 100]$
Assume $F$ and $E$ are normalized to range $[0; 1]$

**Robot1:** $F = 0.2, J = 0.9, E = 0.5$
**Robot2:** $F = 0.5, J = 0.6, E = 0.5$
**Robot3:** $F = 0.9, J = 0.9, E = 0.2$
**Robot4:** $F = 0.6, J = 0.2, E = 0.7$

I need a method of choosing Robot2, because although Robot3 has excellent values for $F$ and $J$, it's $E$ is low. But Robot2 has reasonable values for $F$, $E$ and $J$. I may eventually use more variables than just $F$, $E$ and $J$.

ps: Already saw [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49830/how-do-we-usually-select-the-best-combination-of-parameters-of-a-machine-learnin), [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/168119/multivariate-hypothesis-testing-how-do-you-choose-best-combination-of-factors), [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/135954/selecting-the-best-subset-of-features-in-binary-logistic-regression) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65683/how-to-select-the-optimal-combination-of-input-variables-for-supervised-learning), but they don't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

The way your question is made it does not have a definitive answer. Because you haven't defined what is optimum in your setting.

But I think that you are asking for ideas to define the optimum. So, I'll throw some ideas:

You may interested in [minmax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax), a weighted average, the [geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean) or a [generalized mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean) or other types of [average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average).

From what you said, it seems to me that either the geometric mean or a weighted average could work out.

Another idea was to use something like:
Choose the robot with the highest $F + J + E + k \min(F, J, E)$. Choose the value of $k$ according to your feeling, but you may start by trying $k=1$.